# passing variable to countdown plugin

Tags: jquery, countdown, jsfiddle

How can I pass the information contained in the data-countdown attribute to this jQuery function? I have a test set up at http://jsfiddle.net/G4qLE/ which works when hard coding the time but breaks when replaced with a variable that alerts the same info as the hard code. I am new to jQuery and don't know what I am doing incorrectly any help is greatly  appreciated. Thanks.

```
    <div id="counter" data-countdown="-5, 2013, 5 - 1, 27, 00, 00, 00"></div>

    var countdown = jQuery('#counter').data('countdown');
    //alert(countdown);// alerts -5, 2013, 5 - 1, 27, 00, 00, 00

    jQuery('#counter').countdown({
        until: jQuery.countdown.UTCDate(-5, 2013, 5 - 1, 27, 00, 00, 00),//breaks when replaced with countdown
        compact: true, 
        alwaysExpire: true, 
        expiryText: 'Too Late!'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott said, UTCDate expects a list of arguments, not a string. You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the string to an array and then [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the function using your array values as arguments.

This should give you the desired result:

```
jQuery('#counter').countdown({
    until: jQuery.countdown.UTCDate.apply(jQuery.countdown, countdown.split(', ')),
    compact: true, 
    alwaysExpire: true, 
    expiryText: 'Too Late!'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

UTCDate wants a LIST of numeric arguments; you're getting a single string from data-countdown and passing that.  Sounds like you'll need to parse-out the individual values.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to fix is changing `5 - 1` to `4`. (Otherwise you will get Invaid Date because the parameter `'5 - 1'` is a string and won't be `4`)

```
<div id="counter" data-countdown="-5, 2013, 4, 27, 00, 00, 00"></div>
```

Then you could do with (as *@Paulpro* pointed out):

```
jQuery('#counter').countdown({
    until: jQuery.countdown.UTCDate.apply(jQuery.countdown, countdown.split(/\s*,\s*/)),
    compact: true, 
    alwaysExpire: true, 
    expiryText: 'Too Late!'
});
```

***[See the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/G4qLE/1/)***